# Missing product types in GetProductInfo function API for few Windows 10 editions

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, windows-10, pinvoke

I'm using [GetVersionEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getversionexa) and [GetProductInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getproductinfo) APIs via P-Invoke to detect edition of Windows 10 OS as per below code:

P-Invoke declarations:

```
[DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
internal static extern bool GetProductInfo(
int osMajorVersion,
int osMinorVersion,
int spMajorVersion,
int spMinorVersion,
out int edition);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
private static extern bool GetVersionEx(ref OSVERSIONINFOEX osVersionInfo);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
private struct OSVERSIONINFOEX
{
    public int dwOSVersionInfoSize;
    public int dwMajorVersion;
    public int dwMinorVersion;
    public int dwBuildNumber;
    public int dwPlatformId;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)]
    public string szCSDVersion;
    public short wServicePackMajor;
    public short wServicePackMinor;
    public short wSuiteMask;
    public byte wProductType;
    public byte wReserved;
}
```

Code:

```
var edition = "";

var osVersionInfo = new OSVERSIONINFOEX
{
    dwOSVersionInfoSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(OSVERSIONINFOEX))
};

if (GetVersionEx(ref osVersionInfo))
{
    if (osVersionInfo.dwMajorVersion == 10
        && osVersionInfo.wProductType == 1)
    {
        int ed;
        if (GetProductInfo(Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major
                            , Environment.OSVersion.Version.Minor
                            , osVersionInfo.wServicePackMajor
                            , osVersionInfo.wServicePackMinor
                            , out ed))
        {
            switch (ed)
            {
                case PRODUCT_PROFESSIONAL:
                    edition = "Windows 10 Pro";
                    break;
                case PRODUCT_PRO_WORKSTATION:
                    edition = "Windows 10 Pro for Workstations";
                    break;
                case PRODUCT_EDUCATION:
                    edition = "Windows 10 Education";
                    break;
                case PRODUCT_ENTERPRISE:
                    edition = "Windows 10 Enterprise";
                    break;
                //case 0x1234:
                //    edition = "Windows 10 Enterprise 2019 LTSC";
                //    break;
                //case 0x2345:
                //    edition = "Windows 10 Pro Education";
                //    break;
                default:
                    edition = "Unknown";
                    break;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

`pdwReturnedProductType` is the out parameter in `GetProductInfo` API which provides the value of edition as per the table given in the documentation. The documentation is missing the hex values for below editions:

1. Windows 10 Pro Education
2. Windows 10 Enterprise 2019 LTSC

I need these values to cover all editions in my code. Not sure why these codes are missing from official MS documentation.

Comment: https://www.magnumdb.com/search?q=PRODUCT_* will give you from winnt.h PRODUCT_PRO_FOR_EDUCATION=0x000000A4 not sure what the other is maybe PRODUCT_ENTERPRISEG=0x000000AB

Comment: G = Chinese Government Edition  @SimonMourier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is documented in `winnt.h` in Windows SDK `(C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.BUILDNUMBER.0\um)`

```
#define PRODUCT_PRO_FOR_EDUCATION                   0x000000A4
#define PRODUCT_ENTERPRISE_S                        0x0000007D
```

This PRODUCT_ENTERPRISE_S is LTSB/LTSC version.

To check which LTSB/LTSC version you use, also read `ReleaseID` from registry. 1809 is 2019 LTSC, 1607 is 2016 long term version LTSB.

Comment: This is not what I call "documented"

Comment: everything included in official SDK headers means documented

Comment: Only the value and it's raw cryptic dev name is documented. I don't call that documented. I don't see in any .h that "PRODUCT_ENTERPRISE_S" is LTSB/LTSC version or G is for Chinese Government Edition. If it was documented, there wouldn't be any question about it.

Comment: [ms docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getproductinfo) show PRODUCT_ENTERPRISE_S, PRODUCT_PRO_FOR_EDUCATION is self-explanatory

Comment: Is there any other place where I can verify `PRODUCT_ENTERPRISE_S` constant that it corresponds to `LTSB/LTSC Enterprise` edition. I'm asking this as its name isn't obvious as in the case of `PRODUCT_PRO_FOR_EDUCATION`.

Comment: it is listed on the MS documentation page I linked and I already tested in with LTSC version. To check which LTSB/LTSC version you use, also read ReleaseID. 1809 is 2019, 1607 is 2016 long term version.